# Cannot set environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am having trouble setting my environment variable in Java as I do not see the env var set in linux when I execute `strings /proc/<PID>/environ`.

In Java, I am setting via `set("my-key", "true")` and verifying it has been set with `get("my-key")`. My app is then not running as expected. Executing `strings /proc/<PID>/environ` shows the env var (my-key) has not been set. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public static String get(String key) {
    return System.getenv(key);
}

public static void set(String key, String value) {
    getAll().put(key, value);
}

public static void remove(String key) {
    getAll().remove(key);
}

public static Map<String, String> getAll() {
    try {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        Class<?> cl = env.getClass();
        Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (Map<String, String>) field.get(env);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get environment variables", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're breaking into an internal `Map` and manually adding and removing entries. There's no way that's going to trigger the process's environment to be modified. It's just fiddling with an in-memory cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are immutable. You cannot set them from inside the current process.

Consider other solutions like System properties.

Comment: Fiddling with that map isn't going to change the actual environment (in the `/proc/<PID>/environ` sense).